Copy and paste macro randomly deleting one cell
So I have a macro that copy and pastes a template that links it to the main template that populates data. This all works great but for some reason B20s formula
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(",'Setup Sheet Values'!V45)), MID('Setup Sheet Values'!V45,FIND("(",'Setup Sheet Values'!V45,1),FIND(")",'Setup Sheet Values'!V45,1)),"")
is deleted when I add a new outing. Also for example lets say I have here and in starting pressures 2 up from the name I put 20, as soon as I hit "Add outing" which is a button with this macro `
 Sub Add_Outing()
' Disable screen updating for performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Find the last used row in the Run Log sheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Run Log").Cells(Sheets("Run Log").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Define the next available row for the new outing
Dim nextRow As Long
nextRow = lastRow + 1

' Copy formulas and formats from the Template tab
Sheets("Template").Range("A200:AJ223").Copy
Sheets("Run Log").Cells(nextRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

' Set row height for the new rows
Sheets("Run Log").Rows(nextRow & ":" & nextRow + 23).RowHeight = 14

' Clear the yellow box fill color in cell A4 of the newly pasted range
Sheets("Run Log").Cells(nextRow, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

' Handle merged cells - Clear contents of "Change Comments" and "Time" in the new outing
' Assuming "Change Comments" is merged starting at column D
With Sheets("Run Log").Cells(nextRow + 10, 4)
    If .MergeCells Then
        .UnMerge
        .ClearContents
        .Merge
    Else
        .ClearContents
    End If
End With

' Assuming "Time" is merged starting at column B
With Sheets("Run Log").Cells(nextRow - 7, 2)
    If .MergeCells Then
        .UnMerge
        .ClearContents
        .Merge
    Else
        .ClearContents
    End If
End With

' Re-enable screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

it randomly deletes any value/formula in B20. Also this macro also deletes any value in the next outing in this "particular cell" (the cell number changes but its always in this specific template cell) the macro gets the template which looks like this which in the cell has a different one that just is =IF(ISBLANK(C201)," ",B193) (it changes dynamically) Im just at a loss at how to make this work bc its such a stupid thing.
Protected/locked the formula (still deletes)
Reformatted the forumla in the cell
tried to just paste the formula in b20 so it would update all the time with static numbers (didn't work)
Last thing of advice: this thing was created in 2001 if that helps at all

What's the value of nextRow when this is run?

its just defines the next row for pasting

What does Debug.Print nextRow return to the Immediate Window?

let me check vvv
